# Why does this regex not match?

Tags: java, regex

I'm sure this type of question gets posted a lot here. I have this regex:

```
^\[.*\]
```

which should match

```
[Test]Hi there
```

And according to [RegexPal](http://www.regexpal.com/), it does. However, in this Java SCCE it doesn't:

```
final String pat = "^\\[.*\\]";
final String str = "[Test]Hi there";
System.out.println(pat);
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(str.matches(pat));
```

Output:

```
^\[.*\]
[Test]Hi there
false
```

Why doesn't it match?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

["match"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) in Java means "matches the whole string":

> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

Since your regex doesn't accept any characters after the last `]` it will not "match" anything that has characters after the `]`.

You can use [`find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) to see if the string *contains* something that's matched by your regex (it will still have to be anchored at the beginning, since you use `^`).

In other words `^\[.*\]` will *not* **match** `[Test]Hi there`, but it will **find** `[Test]` within `[Test]Hi there`.

Comment: I've extended the pattern to `(?s)^\[.*\].*`

Answer (score 1):

Because `String#match` will try to match your regex against the whole string. What you're looking for is `Pattern.compile(pat).matcher(str).find()`, see [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).